# Flutter Windows Error ( Exception: Build process failed. )

Tags: windows, flutter, build, flutter-windows

I was working on a project for school management app and it worked perfect on android and windows but after I added firebase for the project it did not build windows again

here is the error that on vs code terminal

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Windows in debug mode...
main.dart:1
Exception: Build process failed.
Exited (sigterm)
```

I tried to build windows in another projects and it worked
I also tried to delete and download a new windows folder for the same project and it did not work too
I run flutter doctor and find no issues !

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.2604], locale en-US)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.4.5)
[√] Android Studio (version 4.2)
[√] VS Code (version 1.75.1)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
[√] HTTP Host Availability

• No issues found!
```

Comment: have you found solution to this or what worked for you? i'm currently facing same issue on my Windows.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me in Windows is upgrading Flutter. From the terminal, enter:
flutter upgrade

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. A restart of VS Code did not help this time, but it is always worth trying.

What did help:

1. `flutter clean`
2. `flutter pub get`